# One specific file missing from injected bower_components

Tags: angularjs, bower

I just installed [Angular UI Grid](http://ui-grid.info/) via Bower.

My `bower_components` directory looks like this:

```
.
..
angular
angular-animate
angular-cookie
angular-cookies
angular-mocks
angular-resource
angular-sanitize
angular-touch
angular-ui-grid <-- the interesting directory
angular-ui-router
angularjs-rails-resource
bootstrap-sass-official
fontawesome
jquery
ng-token-auth
```

Confusingly, my index file looks like this:

```
    <!-- build:js(src) scripts/vendor.js -->
    <!-- bower:js -->
    <script src="../bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="../bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="../bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="../bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js"></script>
    <script src="../bower_components/angular-touch/angular-touch.js"></script>
    <script src="../bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
    <script src="../bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script>
    <script src="../bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
    <script src="../bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/assets/javascripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="../bower_components/angular-cookie/angular-cookie.js"></script>
    <script src="../bower_components/ng-token-auth/dist/ng-token-auth.js"></script>
    <script src="../bower_components/angularjs-rails-resource/angularjs-rails-resource.js"></script>
    <!-- endbower -->
    <!-- endbuild -->
```

Notice the absence of `angular-ui-grid`.

It's not that there are no `.js` files in `bower_components/angular-ui-grid`:

```
$ find bower_components/angular-ui-grid -name '*.js'
bower_components/angular-ui-grid/ui-grid.js
bower_components/angular-ui-grid/ui-grid.min.js
```

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah ha. I had `angular-ui-grid` in `devDependencies` in `bower.json`. It needed to be in `dependencies`.